# RadGridView: can't hide my tooltip for row on true or false

Tags: wpf, telerik, tooltip, row, radgridview

I have this code for style, he shows my tooltip correct, but i want to enable only on 1 view with showallcolumns (true/false):

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}">
         <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ShowAllColumns}" />
         <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding OrderStatus.Translation}" />
     </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the binding source for `ToolTipService.IsEnabled` property. The DataContext for GridViewRow is it`s item, and, in my view, the ShowAllColums property is in the ViewModel. Try specifying the binding source like

```
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView} ,Path=DataContext.ShowAllColumns}" />
```

or any other way.